# How to Count Sub Comments from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the comments table with the following fields

```
comment_id                      
parent_id                       
thread_id 
title   
body                
date_comment                            
user_name
```

I need to retrieve all the parent comments (having NULL Value in parent_id) and count the sub comments against each parent comment
I have tried the following query

```
SELECT c1. * , COUNT( c2.parent_id ) 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL 
AND c1.thread_id =122
GROUP BY c2.parent_id
ORDER BY c1.date_comment ASC
```

But this query counts the sub comments of only first three parent comments.
Please analyze the query and suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God. I got the Solution

```
SELECT c1. * , COUNT( c2.parent_id ) 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL 
AND c1.thread_id =122
GROUP BY c1.comment_id
ORDER BY c1.date_comment ASC
```

as @Erik Schierboom said I was Grouping by `c2.parent_id` When I replaced `GROUP BY c2.parent_id` with `GROUP BY c1.comment_id` my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are grouping on the parent_id of the joined class. This has the effect you describe, where comments that don't have children are ignored. I think this would work:

```
SELECT c1.*, COUNT( c2.parent_id ) AS childcount
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.thread_id =122
GROUP BY c1.comment_id
ORDER BY c1.date_comment ASC
```

You can see my solution as an SQLFiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8997/1

Comment: It works fine but only one problem. It gives 1 either there is no child comment or one child comment. If child comments are more than 1 it gives correct result

Comment: @RashidFarooq I fixed the problem in my query and have edited my answer. I believe it now works as you would like it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Untested query due to a lack of sample data, but I hope it works.

Generating a table with only the counts grouped by parent_id and joining it with the original table:

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.n
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) as n
            FROM comments
            WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY parent_id ) c2
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY c1.date_comment ASC;
```